# Mongoose are returning undefined value of property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Well, I'm trying to get a value of property from a object with Mongoose find(), but for some reason, the mongoose are returning a undefined value.

The Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  dsID: { type: String, unique: true, require: true },
  dsTag: { type: String },

  mcCode: { type: String, default: () => uuid.v4(), unique: true, select: false },
  mcConnected: { type: Boolean, default: false }

}, { versionKey: false });

const Members = mongoose.model("Members", Schema);
module.exports = Members;
```

The code

```js
// Database connection
mongoose.connect(DATABASE.uri, DATABASE.options);

Members.find({ 'dsID': dsID }, (err, member) => {
  const connected = member.mcConnected;

  console.log(connected)
});
```

Comment: Db connection is an async op. You need to make sure the `Model.find()` happens after the connection is established.

Comment: Well, i tried, but mongoose are returning undefined yet

Comment: It's weird, because here I made with the same way and get no problems: https://github.com/Seface-Blocks/seface-bot/commit/038bc3c04f2802d1f53a16a527f35977a10763a4#diff-7312cb5ae273841f91687f5a029cc3d8

Comment: Meant [something like this](https://imgur.com/0M2fyhV). Try that out, with focus on the callback function `connection.once("open", function () ..)` which executes once the connection is established.

Comment: A new error: "once is not a Function"

Comment: It is: [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) see the first example.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of you should not name a model 'Schema'. Try with other name because "Schema" is reserved word

Comment: Could u point  to a documentation or something where it is written that `Schema` is reserved keyword and one cannot name a variable `Schema`.

Comment: In his mind, I went to research since I had never seen anything like that where he said it was a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on schema

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const memberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  dsID: { type: String, unique: true, require: true },
  dsTag: { type: String },

  mcCode: { type: String, default: () => uuid.v4(), unique: true, select: false },
  mcConnected: { type: Boolean, default: false }

}, { versionKey: false });

const Members = mongoose.model("Members", memberSchema);
module.exports = Members;
```

Comment: Already tried this, the problem isn't the Schema name, Schema isn't a reserved word

Comment: @LeonardoGava the problem is not with variable name but you've not created instance of mongoose using new keyword.

Comment: Ok, but the problem isn't it too, I tried it. I think the problem is on the code, and not on Schema

Answer (score 0):

Here u go boys:

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000

//MongoDB Connection
const DB_Connect = require('./(8.1)MongoDB_Connection')
const DB = DB_Connect() //returning a Model

//Middleware
const logger = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('logging')
    next()
}
app.use(logger)

//Routes
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    console.log(DB.then((docs) => {
        console.log(docs.find({ name: 'POCO X3 Pro' }, (error, docs) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error)
            } else {
                console.log(docs)
            }
        }))
    }))
})

/*

DB is a Model and console.log(DB) gives : " Promise { Model { users } } ".

But for Promise we use .then() for result.
    Model { users }

As we use .find(), we got the answer

*/

//Listening
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))

//Muhammad Irtaza Ghaffar (Pakistan)
```

Thanks me later!